# 継承を利用せずに、ListとDictと互換性のあるクラスを作成したい

Tags: python, python3

継承を利用せずに、（例えばListやDictのインスタンスを包含して、）
ListとDictと互換性のあるクラスを作成したいのですが、
実装するべきメソッド（__から始まるメソッド）を教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
class SampleList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = [1, 2, 3]

    def __iter__(self):  # イテレータの実装
        return (data for data in self.list)

for value in SampleList():
    print(value)
```

さらにスライスの実装も必要
Len()の実装も必要
他に必要なインターフェースありますでしょうか？
Dictクラスについてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ドキュメントが参考になるかと思います。https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
CPythonのソースコードもあります。https://github.com/python/cpython

Comment: 「__から始まるメソッド」ということなら、こちらでは https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types

Comment: 「ListとDictと互換性のあるクラス」ということなら、こちらも https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes

Comment: ありがとうございます。これだという一覧表はなさそうですね。もう少し読み進めていきます。

Comment: `[m for m in dir(dict) if m.startswith('__')]` や `[m for m in dir(list) if m.startswith('__')]` でよいのでは。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listやdictのメソッドの一覧を取得するのであれば、次のワンライナーで確認できると思います。

```
# list
(lambda x: print(*[s for s in dir(x) if callable(getattr(x, s))], sep='\n'))([])
# dict
(lambda x: print(*[s for s in dir(x) if callable(getattr(x, s))], sep='\n'))({})
```

なお、「継承を利用せず」が「**標準で継承されてしまうobject以外のあらゆるクラスからの**継承を利用せず」ではなく「**dictとlistからの**継承を利用せず」と言う意味であれば、`collections.abc`にある抽象基底クラスを継承して、最低限必要なメソッドのみ実装し、他のメソッドはmixinによって自動定義したほうがいいでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

`collections.abc`のドキュメントが参考になるはずです。

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html

組み込みクラスはこのモジュールで定義されるABCの「仮想サブクラス」である場合がある、と記載されています。実際に、`dict`は`MutableMapping`を、`list`は`MutableSequence`を仮想継承していることが確認できます。

```
In [1]: from collections.abc import MutableMapping, MutableSequence

In [2]: issubclass(dict, MutableMapping)
Out[2]: True

In [3]: issubclass(list, MutableSequence)
Out[3]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

ありがとうございます。
おおむね理解できました。

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.htmlより、継承関係を整理しました。

◇Listの継承関係
MutableSequenceクラス継承し、
以下の、赤字の５メソッドを実装すればよい、ことが分かりました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

◇Dictの継承関係
「MutableMappingクラスを継承し、
以下の、赤字の５メソッドを実装すればよい、ことが分かりました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これで、コレクションの自作ができそうです。
実際にやってみて、応用していきます。
ありがとうございました。